# PHP json_encode() values returning null

Tags: php

UPDATED: ALL Values now returning "A" when they should all be different values.
What I am trying to do is, send a table of values via post request to my website, and the website will save the table data to a text file. I finally have it so the entire table prints to the text document but all the values are A.What am I doing wrong? By the way, I have tried many methods and many other "Similar Questions" and none have worked for me. Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
<?php
$foo = file_get_contents("php://input");
$stuff = json_decode($foo, true);

function createtxt($cttext, $location,$stuff)
{
    $ccontent  = $cttext;
    if (file_exists($location)) {
        echo "The file $ffilename exists";
    } else {
        $fp = fopen($location, "wb");
        fclose($fp);
                $formdata = array(
                'user'=> $cttext['user'],
                'secretkey'=> $cttext['secretkey'],
                'isanadmin'=> $cttext['isa'],
                'firsttime'=> $cttext['firsttime'],
                'display'=> $cttext['dis'],
                'test'=> $cttext['test'],
                'test2'=> $cttext['test2'],
                'type'=> $cttext['type']
                );
                $jsondata = json_encode($formdata);
                file_put_contents($location, $jsondata);
        echo 'Created User Text File Named "data.txt" ';
    }
}

function lookforuser($NAME,$stuff)
{
    if (!file_exists('users/' . $NAME))
        mkdir('users/' . $NAME);
    echo 'User Folder Created ';
    createtxt($NAME, 'users/' . $NAME . '/data.txt',$stuff);
}

lookforuser($stuff['user'],$stuff);
?>
```

OUTPUT IN TEXT FILE:

```
{"user":"A","secretkey":"A","isanadmin":"A","firsttime":"A","display":"A","test":"A","test2":"A","type":"A"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass in `$cttext`, but access `$stuff`.

Since `$stuff` isn't defined, array dereferencing is null too.

You might want to pass `$stuff` as a third parameter.

Comment: SOLVED!

Output now is:

{"user":"ASCORE","secretkey":"secretkeytheyentered","isanadmin":"0","firsttime":"1","display":"0","test":"Works!","test2":"Works!","type":"0"}
 Changed all the $cttext[] to $stuff[] n the updated script
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$stuff` is never defined inside your function. It's a global variable, but you don't pass it to your function; the function only knows about its parameters, variables initialized internally, and variables explicitly referenced via `global`. You do pass the *contents* of `$stuff` to `createtxt` because of the way you call `lookforuser` and then `createtxt`, however.

So, **the best way to fix this:** replace `$stuff` with `$cttext` every time you use `$stuff` in the function `createtxt`. You are already passing the values of `$stuff` to `createtxt` because of the way you wrote your code, so this will work.

Full code:

```
function createtxt($cttext, $location)
{
    $ccontent  = $cttext;
    if (file_exists($location)) {
        echo "The file $ffilename exists";
    } else {
        $fp = fopen($location, "wb");
        fclose($fp);
                $formdata = array(
                'user'=> $cttext['user'],
                'secretkey'=> $cttext['secretkey'],
                'isanadmin'=> $cttext['isa'],
                'firsttime'=> $cttext['firsttime'],
                'display'=> $cttext['dis'],
                'test'=> $cttext['test'],
                'test2'=> $cttext['test2'],
                'type'=> $cttext['type']
                );
                $jsondata = json_encode($formdata);
                file_put_contents($location, $jsondata);
        echo 'Created User Text File Named "data.txt" ';
    }
}

function lookforuser($NAME)
{
    if (!file_exists('users/' . $NAME))
        mkdir('users/' . $NAME);
    echo 'User Folder Created ';
    createtxt($NAME, 'users/' . $NAME . '/data.txt');
}

lookforuser($stuff['user']);
?>
```

Comment: $stuff is global, but it's passed as an arg to `lookforuser()`, which passes it on to the other two functions. I'll be that OP's totally confused by his wild swapping of variable names as they got through call chain. $NAME -> $cttext and whatnot.

Comment: @MarcB No, it passes the *values* of `$stuff`, not the variable itself. `$stuff` is undefined in either `lookforuser` or `createtxt`, but the values in `$stuff` are accessible through `$NAME` and `$cttext`, respectively.

Comment: `lookforuser($stuff['name'], $stuff)`. looks like it's passing it to me....

Comment: @MarcB That just passes the values; it doesn't allow you to use the variable name `$stuff` inside the function. Try it. `$foo = 'bar'; function myfunc($myvar) { echo $foo; } myfunc($foo);` It doesn't work, because `$foo` is undefined in the scope of `myfunc()`.

Comment: yeah, but OP doesn't have `myvar` in his function defintions. `function lookforuser($NAME, $stuff) { ...} ; lookforuser($stuff['name'], $stuff)`. $stuff is passed in and WILL be available. It's your code that doesn't have stuff being passed around.

Comment: That's just not correct. You can't refer to a global variable inside a function simply because you passed the *contents* of that variable as a parameter to the function.

Comment: See my "answer" below. You're totally wrong

Comment: You missed the point. If you name a parameter `$stuff`, then of course `$stuff` is accessible in the function. If you name the parameter `$foo`, like `function myfunct($foo)`, then try to refer to `$stuff` by name in the function, it won't work. That's what OP did, which is why it didn't work. In the edited question, yes, there is a parameter named $stuff. That wasn't true before. Adding that parameter made OP's problem go away, but with the result that OP now passes the same data in two different parameters (and, apparently, totally missed the reason for the bug, which was a scoping problem).

Comment: Ah yeah, my apologies. Looked at the edit history and yeah... $stuff wasn't in the original posted code.